# Android, как создать директорию на SD карте или телефоне

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Как правильно создать папку на Android?
Например я создал программу, которая сверяет файлы в папке и полученными из запроса.

После скачивания файла делаю так:

```
 File file = new File(FILE_PATH + fileName);
                        File dir = new File(FILE_PATH);
                        dir.mkdir();
                        file.createNewFile();
```

Где:

```
fileName = Peter Gabriel - My body is a cage.mp3; (например)

public static String FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator+"projName"  + File.separator;
```

На эмуляторе 23 API - ошибка при создании файла, а на 15 API все нормально.

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-18 19:49:16.065 9750-11201/com.letit0or1.VkAudio W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
02-18 19:49:16.065 9750-11201/com.letit0or1.VkAudio W/System.err:     at com.letit0or1.VkAudio.Adapter.AudioListAdapter$3.run(AudioListAdapter.java:207)
02-18 19:49:16.065 9750-11201/com.letit0or1.VkAudio W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-18 19:49:16.065 9750-11201/com.letit0or1.VkAudio W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-18 19:49:16.065 9750-11201/com.letit0or1.VkAudio W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-18 19:49:16.065 9750-11201/com.letit0or1.VkAudio W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
02-18 19:49:16.065 9750-11201/com.letit0or1.VkAudio W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
02-18 19:49:16.065 9750-11201/com.letit0or1.VkAudio W/System.err:   ... 2 more
```

Comment: Возможно, вы не учли изменения в политике раздачи разрешений с 23 апи. Их теперь надо в рантайме запрашивать у юзера. Скорее всего в логах это отражено, но вы их от нас решили скрыть, вот мы и гадаем.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [mkdirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) чтобы создать папку.

Вот маленький пример как можно создать файл и папку:

```
// создание объекта файла в указанной папке
File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
// построение структуры каталогов(если необходимо)
wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
// создание файла для записи.
File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, filename);
// прикрепление потока для вывода в файл
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

Возможно нужно будет разрешить запись, в таком случае используйте это:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил, что вы используете mkdirs(), тогда скорее всего дело в разрешении.

Comment: я подозреваю, что проблема в отсуствии флешки на 23 API, хотя, могу ошибатся